# How to restrict access to certain Foxx service arangodb

Tags: arangodb, foxx

For example, I have 2 services A and B. I would like to expose A that everyone can use and B as restricted to "root" user stored in arangodb. Does arangodb support it?

Answer (score 0):

For the root service you can specify some header parameters that you will check in your foxx service. Or you may be check if the arangouser is logged see authentication cookbook. If yes check if the user is root.